# pool allocator with Microsoft STL's std::map

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, allocator

I'm trying to use [this allocator](https://probablydance.com/2014/11/09/plalloc-a-simple-stateful-allocator-for-node-based-containers/) with `std::map` on VS2017, however it is failing debug mode asserts so there seems to be something wrong. Here's a minimal sample of the code after trimming it down.

```
#include "plalloc.hpp"
#include <map>

typedef unsigned char uchar;

struct my_info_t
{
  int src, dst;
  char type;
  bool operator <(const my_info_t &r) const
  {
    if ( src < r.src )
      return true;
    if ( src > r.src )
      return false;
    return dst < r.dst;
  }
};

typedef plalloc<std::pair<const my_info_t, uchar> > xcache_alloc;
typedef std::map<my_info_t, uchar, std::less<my_info_t>, xcache_alloc> my_cache_t;


int main()
{
 my_cache_t xc;
 my_info_t xi = {1, 2, 3};
 xc[xi] =42;
}
```

In the original code it was breaking on this line in `<xtree>`:

```
 #if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
        _STL_VERIFY(_Where._Getcont() == _STD addressof(_My_data), "map/set insert iterator outside range");
 #endif /* _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2 */
```

However, with the stripped-down sample I'm getting a deleted pointer access in `_Iterator_base12::_Adopt()`:

```
    void _Adopt(const _Container_base12 *_Parent) noexcept
        {   // adopt this iterator by parent
        if (_Parent == nullptr)
            {   // no future parent, just disown current parent
 #if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
            _Lockit _Lock(_LOCK_DEBUG);
            _Orphan_me();
 #endif /* _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2 */
            }
        else
            {   // have a parent, do adoption
            _Container_proxy *_Parent_proxy = _Parent->_Myproxy; // <== **** CRASH HERE
```

The `_Parent` has value 0xdddddddd, so it's been deleted.  Here's the full stack trace:

```
>   Project1.exe!std::_Iterator_base12::_Adopt(const std::_Container_base12 * _Parent=0xdddddddd) Line 157  C++
    Project1.exe!std::_Iterator_base12::operator=(const std::_Iterator_base12 & _Right={...}) Line 135  C++
    Project1.exe!std::_Iterator_base12::_Iterator_base12(const std::_Iterator_base12 & _Right={...}) Line 116   C++
    Project1.exe!std::_Tree_unchecked_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<my_info_t const ,unsigned char> > >,std::_Iterator_base12>::_Tree_unchecked_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<my_info_t const ,unsigned char> > >,std::_Iterator_base12>(const std::_Tree_unchecked_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<my_info_t const ,unsigned char> > >,std::_Iterator_base12> & __that={...})  C++
    Project1.exe!std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<my_info_t const ,unsigned char> > > >::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<my_info_t const ,unsigned char> > > >(const std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<my_info_t const ,unsigned char> > > > & __that={...})   C++
    Project1.exe!std::map<my_info_t,unsigned char,std::less<my_info_t>,plalloc<std::pair<my_info_t const ,unsigned char> > >::_Try_emplace<my_info_t const &>(const my_info_t & _Keyval={...}) Line 232 C++
    Project1.exe!std::map<my_info_t,unsigned char,std::less<my_info_t>,plalloc<std::pair<my_info_t const ,unsigned char> > >::try_emplace<>(const my_info_t & _Keyval={...}) Line 248   C++
    Project1.exe!std::map<my_info_t,unsigned char,std::less<my_info_t>,plalloc<std::pair<my_info_t const ,unsigned char> > >::operator[](const my_info_t & _Keyval={...}) Line 363  C++
    Project1.exe!main() Line 29 C++
```

Unfortunately, the Dinkumware-originating code is pretty obscure (especially the proxy allocator thingy - what's that?) so it's difficult to figure out what is going on. Is the problem in the allocator, my use of it, or Microsoft's STL?

Comment: `plalloc` doesn't meet allocator requirements, e.g. a requirement that a copy of an allocator must compare equal to the original (note that "compare equal" further implies "be able to deallocate memory allocated by the other"). [In this table](https://eel.is/c++draft/allocator.requirements#tab:cpp17.allocator), look for "*Postconditions:* `u == a`" The caller must be able to do `my_cache_t a; auto p = my_cache_t(a).allocate(1); my_cache_t(a).deallocate(p, 1);` But with `plalloc`, `p` would become dangling right after the `allocate` call when the `my_cache_t(a)` temporary is destroyed.

Comment: In practice, what MSVC STL implementation does is something like `Alloc a; DebugInfo* p = std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::rebind_alloc<DebugInfo>(a).allocate(1);` where `DebugInfo` is some internal data it keeps track of in debug builds only (to be precise, builds with _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL > 0), e.g. to diagnose the use of invalidated iterators. That breaks with `plalloc`; `p` becomes dangling immediately. This feature of MSVC STL tends to smoke out bad allocator implementations.